# Delete word backward without coping it to buffer

Tags: kill-buffer

<sub>(I feel like there should be duplicate for this, but I could not find it. Pardon me.)</sub>

## Question

How can I delete word backwards without it being copied to buffer?

## Explanation

I developed a habit of coping text from somewhere, coming to emacs, using <kbd>M</kbd>-<kbd>Backspace</kbd> to delete some text, and then yank (<kbd>C</kbd>-<kbd>y</kbd>). Unfortunately, it is bound to `backward-kill-word`, which "overwrites" whatever I just copied from another place. I am looking for  `delete-backward-char`-like functionality, but for words (like `delete-backward-word`) and I want it to be bound to <kbd>M</kbd>-<kbd>Backspace</kbd>. I suspect I just don't use emacs properly or "not thinking the emacs way". Should I change my habit? If so, then how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(defun my-delete-backward-word ()
  (interactive "*")
  (push-mark)
  (backward-word)
  (delete-region (point) (mark)))
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you! I've been suffering with this for a few years now, but no more.

Comment: I started using windows 10 and emacs 26.1 and it looks like it stopped working.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the nice solution provided by @AndreasRohler , you could use `counsel-yank-pop`, from the `counsel` package, instead of `yank` here. The workflow would then be:

1. Copy text from outside emacs
2. Move to emacs and `M-backspace` to delete the old text
3. Paste with `M-y`, i.e., `counsel-yank-pop`, and choose the second option (your copied text)

This requires one additional keystroke over @AndreasRohler's solution. However, it preserves the behaviour of `M-backspace`, and doesn't require a new keybinding for `my-delete-backward-word`, so that might be a worthwhile tradeoff, depending on how frequently you want to use `backward-kill-word` vs `my-delete-backward-word`.